# android and qualcomm OpenCL compilation

Tags: android, opencl, qualcomm

i wanted to try adreno GPU for developement. I got an xiaomi MI10T PRO with adreno 650. Lokk fast with vulkan by the way ;))

So i am trying to use it for OpenCL development and i got big problem of compilation.

I just wanted to know if it is possible to develope with adreno smartphone GPU or not.

I use ARM mali without any problem on my Honnor play.

Wath i found out is that the OpenCL function name on le libOpenCL are different from the one in ARM mali.

in ARM mali "clGetPlatformInfo" is "clGetPlatformInfo"

in qualcomm adreno "clGetPlatformInfo" is "qCLDrvAPI_clGetPlatformInfo" everithing belong with "qCLDrvAPI_"

So it look like the INCLUDE/CL from ARM and Qualcomm are different, not the same name.

Does anyone have already succed to develope ander android studio with qualcomm adreno ?

And the worst is that the libOpenCL.so and libGLES_android found on my smatphone have a date of 01/01/2009.

It look like qualcomm is not very fun of android studio development tools ?

But i may be wrong ;))

thanks for the help, so i wont spend one more week trying something taht cannot work.

regards Herve Terrolle

Answer (score 0):

i have found tha problem of compilation.

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := GLES_android OpenCL

if i add OpenCL to the  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES the compilation is done ;))